# Java - Pack all class methods in try{ }catch block

Tags: java

Is there any way to pack all class methods in try{ }catch block without writing it in each method?

in example I have that class:

```
class Sample{
  public void test(){
    try{
      ...
    }catch(){
      //doing rollback
    } 
  }

  public void test2(){
    try{
      ...
    }catch(){
      //doing rollback
    } 
  }
}
```

I don't want to write that try catch block for each method. is there any way to extract try..catch block to some code and "inject" it in each method?

Comment: Are you using any DI framework?

Comment: why do you want to do that? may there is a better solution.

Comment: well there is AOP - personally I find it tedious, but maybe it can help you.

Comment: Each method in that class will do some multi-query SQL code and I want to prevent any database zombie entries. Thats why in each I want to do try catch block and rollback changhes if exception occurs.

Comment: By making the methods throwing the exceptions (i.e. `public void test() throws YourException`)? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your code into the method which handle exceptions like this:

```
public void runTest(Runnable code) {
    try {
        code.run();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //doing rollback
    }
}
```

Then call it method inside each your test() methods:

```
public void test1() {
    runTest(new Runnable {
        //your code here
    });
}
```

Comment: There will be performance issue as they are running in a separate thread. (Additional memory for thread allocation)

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using any AOP framework, you can use [Java Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to call class methods. During proxy class call, you can handle exception (begin/end transaction etc.) Most of the AOP frameworks work like that.

Comment: A point to add: Java Dynamic Proxy only create proxy for your interfaces.  In case we need to create proxy of a concrete class, cglib or javassit is something worth to look at

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it at the source level, I'm afraid. But AOP to the rescue - take a look at [aspectj](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/), for example, or any other AOP framework.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what do you need to do inside rollback you could write your code using try with resource feature added to Java 7.

But not sure if this is your use case.

Basically if I want a file do be closed in case of an exception my code will look like:

```
try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
    //process data
    ...
}
```

for the original code of:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
try {
    //process data
    ...
} finally {
   try{
     in.close();
   }catch(Exception e){
   }
}
```

Using this approach you will only need the try block.

a good reference is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you may benefit from integrating your application with Spring.

You can then use spring transaction handling to handle your database transactions.

See here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html

But it essentially involves defining your datasource and a transaction manager in the configurations, and then annotating each method with `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Sample s= new Sample();
    try{
        s.test();
        s.test2();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
class Sample{
  public void test() throws Exception{
  }
  public void test2() throws Exception{
  }
}
```

Its a good practice to catch all the exception at `main` until and unless you need it in specific `methods`

Comment: Ok, redirecting exception to higher levels is allways an option. But I n that case there is problem if someone will forget do "catch" properly in his code while using my class.

Comment: Yeah, There might be. You can catch some specific Exception at method level and rest leave to the higher level user to handle. And in IDE's when you call the method, it informed you about the exception which might be throw while program executes.

Answer (score 0):

your methods could throw different exceptions, and the `rollback` could be different too. so it would be ok to keep them in individual method

However if you say that, all methods are `void`, the exception thrown by those method would be same, and the rollback functions are identical too, you could do it in this way, I am not sure if it looks better:

```
class Sample{
 public enum MethodFlag {Test1,Test2}

 public void doStuff(MethodFlag flag){
   try{
    if (flag==MethodFlag.Test1)
        test1();
    if(flag==MethodFlag.Test2)
        test2();
   }catch(FooException ex){
     rollback();
   }
 }

 private void test1(){...}
 private void test2(){...}
}


//calling it
Sample sample = new Sample();
sample.doStuff(Sample.MethodFlag.Test1);
```

didn't write in IDE, hope no typoes, just showing the idea.